# How to write FileSystemWatcher without triggering an infinite loop

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

**How do I write a file in C# to a folder path that is watched by FileSystemWatcher?**

My fileSystemWatcher settings are as follows:

```
public FileSystemWatcher CreateAndExecute(string path)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Watching " + path);

    //Create new watcher
    FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

    fileSystemWatcher.Path = path;
    fileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
    fileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | 
    NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

    fileSystemWatcher.Filter = "*.txt";
    fileSystemWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChange);

    fileSystemWatcher.InternalBufferSize = 32768;

    //Execute
    fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void OnChange(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    //Replace modified file with original copy
}
```

I want to replace a modified file's contents with a back up copy from a database whenever an unauthorized write (out of the program) happens to the file.

However, when i write using File.WriteAllText() to the modified file, it triggers a Change event by the FileSystemWatcher as the action is registered as a write again.

This causes the program to run in an endless loop of overwriting the file it has just wrote.

How can I replace the modified file with the backup copy, without triggering another event to write by FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: In a good manner? You can't. Detect it, keep a list of which files you've restored and watch for the event that follows, or detect that the file you just detected a write to is exactly how it should be so no action need to be taken.

Comment: Could you un-bind the OnChange event once it fires and then rebind after you've written the file? There is the danger there though that you would miss a file whilst unbound. Just a thought.

Comment: You are saying "from a database" and that makes me suspect those files are intended to be used by a particular application. If so, then wouldn't it be possible, instead of keeping the files on the disk, the application gets from the database, do whatever (and maybe erase after done).

Comment: How about setting `fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;` at first line of `OnChange`, and setting it to `true` after `File.WriteAllText()` ?

Comment: @raidensan see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50618762/1300910) why you should not do this

Comment: Why are you doing this at all? Why isn't the program just reading the files directly from the database? Why do they have to exist on disk at all? Also, if they're not supposed to be modified by anyone, why not install it under a user that disallows anyone else modifying them? There are good methods, like ACL's, already in place in the operating system to handle this sort of scenario. Note that a "valid" argument would be that an administrator could easily circumvent ACL's, but it is invalid because the same administrator can easily just kill your backup monitor.

Comment: This is quite a bad idea.  FSW is far too limited to do this correctly, you cannot know what account made the change and you can never be sure that you'll restore the file quickly enough.  There is no upper bound on how long that can take either.  Just use normal OS protection, configure the directory to give read and list access to regular users and only write access to admins and backup operators.

Comment: Much thanks to all that helped! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you can probably solve the problem in a better/different way by using the OS file security f.e., you have some options:

- Temporarily disable the watcher, in which case you can loose events in case of a brute force attack, which might not be what you want.
- Keep a list with files you've rewritten and ignore one change for files on the list and remove it from the list afterwards -> can also be abused if the malicious program knows this
- Store a SHA1 or SHA256 (or other hash) of the file content and only replace the file if the hash is different -> probably the best approach for this problem

Comment: Thanks! I think disabling the watcher temporarily should be fine. There is a mechanism for a token, so disabling for awhile should be fine